# How to use a static range and display members according a TOP(x) style query

Tags: iccube, iccube-reporting

We are trying to add a slider jquery widget, and would like to define a static range, say percentage from 0% to 100%. 
Then we would like to use the value from the slider in that range as the parameter for the TOP(x), as shown on the picture.

Is this possible? 
Any hints ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created an example report for you, import it using the  default [Sales] schema
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3kSph_LgXizdk9OdnlTWkxHa1U/view?usp=sharing

You could achieve this functionality by using the next sequence:

1. Create Slider widget
2. Open a widget options dialog and configure widget properties
3. Select Query Wizard -> Query Type: Mdx Hierarchies
4. Add single random hierarchy to bypass validation(it will be replaced)
5. Setup the default value in Initial Selection (i.e. 10%)
6. Add a code to your report javascript

```js
viz.filters.Slider.prototype.componentWillMount = function(){
    if(_.isArray(this.props.items)) 
        this.setState({
          entities:new viz.EntityData(this.props.items),
          range:_.map(this.props.defaults,"uniqueName")
        });
}

viz.filters.Slider.prototype.onBuildAllDone = function(){
    if(!_.isEmpty(this.state.range)) {
        this.fireEvent(vizEventType.onSelection,
                       this.createEvent(this.state.range));
        this.fireEvent(vizEventType.onNewLabel,
                       this.createEvent(this.state.range));
    }
} 

function consumeEvent( context, event ) {                                
  if (event.name == 'ic3-report-init') { 
    // Following code will replace a data provider for Slider
    // with generated numbers. But to do so, you'll need UID of
    // the Slider widget, in this example it's "w1"
    var widget = event.value.widgetMgr().getItemById("w1");
    _.assign(widget.builder().guts_, {
      items:_.times(100, function(idx){
        return {
          name:idx + 1 + "%", 
          uniqueName:idx + 1
        }
      })})                                          
  }                                                                      
}
```

Comment: thank you i see how that can work、 but after importing the sample report i get a javascript error

Comment: Could you tell me the exact version of your reporting? (Admin -> Version)

Comment: - icCube Reporting : 5.1 (2180)
- icCube Server : 5.2 03-May-2016 07:48:42 GMT
(This is running on OSX btw)

Comment: The error is: Javascript error in consume event, Reference error, can't find variable _

Comment: Provided solution is for the version 5.3, do you have the ability to upgrate to the latest version?

Comment: yes for sure. Where is it ? :) the main download page only shows 5.2

Comment: Please, use the latest available on the download page, it contains: icCube Reporting : 5.1.8 (2837) And it's enough to apply provided solution, just checked.