# How to define a slider with dynamic range min/max of data to filter rows

Tags: iccube, iccube-reporting

I am trying to define a filter on rows based on a slider filter where its range is min/max of a given measure instead of the beginning and end of the data (the default behaviour).

Comment: It's not a duplicated of this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38950556/how-to-use-a-static-range-and-display-members-according-a-topx-style-query

Comment: Hi. The difference is being that the reference link above is trying to achieve a filtering based on top x% percentage. While here I am trying to set the from and to of the slider to the minimum and maximum values of the desired measure for the filtering. I am not a very much experienced user, so from my perspective, the issue is how to make it such that the slider picks up the from/to to be the max and min of the measure instead of its first and last element.

Answer (score 1):

slider widget was designed to select ranges of level members, so it doesn't support selection over measure values. You can either try to create own widget based on slider or use statical defined data as in [How to use a static range and display members according a TOP(x) style query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38950556/how-to-use-a-static-range-and-display-members-according-a-topx-style-query), just change:

```
function consumeEvent( context, event ) {                                
  if (event.name == 'ic3-report-init') { 
    // Following code will replace a data provider for Slider
    // with generated numbers. But to do so, you'll need UID of
    // the Slider widget, in this example it's "w1"
    var widget = event.value.widgetMgr().getItemById("w1");
    _.assign(widget.builder().guts_, {
      items:_.times(STEPS_COUNT, function(idx){
        return {
          name:MIN_VALUE + idx * STEP_SIZE, 
          uniqueName:idx
        }
      })})                       
  }                                                                      
}
```

define STEPS_COUNT, MIN_VALUE, STEP_SIZE.
After that you can try to apply event value as the filter to your MDX

Comment: as the slider is designed to select ranges of level members, could you please help me to make it such that the from and to of the slider will be set to the min /max of a given dimension/level?